# DataMapper No Memory Error - Sinatra

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra, datamapper

Any ideas as to where I am going wrong here?

Error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.1.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:291:in `next!': failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.1.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:291:in `select_fields'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.1.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:39:in `select'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.1.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:276:in `with_connection'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.1.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:33:in `select'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-migrations-1.1.0/lib/dm-migrations/adapters/dm-mysql-adapter.rb:99:in `show_variable'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-migrations-1.1.0/lib/dm-migrations/adapters/dm-mysql-adapter.rb:89:in `character_set'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-migrations-1.1.0/lib/dm-migrations/adapters/dm-mysql-adapter.rb:54:in `create_table_statement'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-migrations-1.1.0/lib/dm-migrations/adapters/dm-do-adapter.rb:94:in `create_model_storage'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.1.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:276:in `with_connection'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-migrations-1.1.0/lib/dm-migrations/adapters/dm-do-adapter.rb:93:in `create_model_storage'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-migrations-1.1.0/lib/dm-migrations/adapters/dm-do-adapter.rb:57:in `upgrade_model_storage'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-migrations-1.1.0/lib/dm-migrations/auto_migration.rb:71:in `upgrade_model_storage'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-migrations-1.1.0/lib/dm-migrations/auto_migration.rb:143:in `auto_upgrade!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-migrations-1.1.0/lib/dm-migrations/auto_migration.rb:45:in `send'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-migrations-1.1.0/lib/dm-migrations/auto_migration.rb:45:in `repository_execute'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/support/descendant_set.rb:66:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/support/subject_set.rb:212:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/support/ordered_set.rb:321:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/support/ordered_set.rb:321:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/support/subject_set.rb:212:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/support/descendant_set.rb:65:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-migrations-1.1.0/lib/dm-migrations/auto_migration.rb:44:in `repository_execute'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-migrations-1.1.0/lib/dm-migrations/auto_migration.rb:27:in `auto_upgrade!'
    from list.rb:51
```

Code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'omniauth/oauth'
require 'rest-graph'
require 'hashie/hash'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-serializer/to_json'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'dm-timestamps'
require 'dm-validations'
require 'dm-mysql-adapter'

enable :sessions

APP_ID = "XXXXX"
APP_SECRET = "XXXX"

SQLCONN = "mysql://XXXXXXX"

DataMapper.setup(:default, SQLCONN)

class Person
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :FBid, String
  property :visits, Integer
  property :first_visit, DateTime
  property :recent_visit, DateTime
  property :token, String

  has n, :links
end

class Link
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :created, DateTime
  property :deactivated, DateTime
  property :active, Boolean

  belongs_to :person

  def self.currentLinks
    all(:active == true)
  end
end

DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
all(:active == true)
```

try...

```
all(:active => true)
```